# Merge multiple csv by columns r

Tags: r

I have multiple csv files, and these files contain some identical columns as well as different columns.
For example,

```
#1st.csv
col1,col2 
1,2

#2nd.csv
col1,col3,col4
1,2,3

#3rd.csv
col1,col2,col3,col5
1,2,3,4
```

I try to combine these files based on the same columns, but for those different columns, I simply 
include all columns but fill the cell with NA (for those data without that columns).

So I expect to see:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
1,2,NA,NA,NA            #this is 1st.csv
1,NA,2,3,NA             #this is 2nd.csv
1,2,3,NA,4              #this is 3rd.csv
```

Here is the r code I give, but it returns an error message

```
> Combine_data <- smartbind(1st,2nd,3rd)

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , value = list(ID = c(1001, 1001,  : 
  replacement element 1 has 143460 rows, need 143462
```

Does anyone know any alternative or elegant way to get the expected result?

The R version is 3.3.2.

Comment: try `Combine_data <- plyr::rbind.fill(1st,2nd,3rd)`. That is assuming that you've already imported the data from those csv files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with the `bind_rows` function from `dplyr`

```
df1 <- read.csv(text = "col1, col2 
1,2", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.csv(text = "col1, col3, col4
1,2,3", header = TRUE)

df3 <- read.csv(text = "col1, col2, col3, col5
1,2,3,4", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)

res <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3)
> res
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1    1    2   NA   NA   NA
2    1   NA    2    3   NA
3    1    2    3   NA    4
```